# Content Search Webpart Query for getting items from the list where a particular field is empty

Tags: cswp

Can someone help me with the query for retrieving list items using CSWP where a particular field value is empty.
I have tried the query in the way to exclude a* b* ....z*. It works. But need a better option than this.